# Regarding ant: how i can give few aruments to main function?

Tags: java, ant

Here is my "run" in my ant build file:

```
<target name="run" depends="jar">
        <java fork="true" classname="${main-class}">
            <classpath>


                <path location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>


            </classpath>


        </java>
    </target>
```

I want to run it like this:

```
ant run -Darg0=First.txt -Darg1=Second.txt -Darg2=Third.txt -Darg3=Fourth.txt -Darg4=Fifth.txt
```

What changes should i make in my "run"?

Many thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the ant task to run any program (including, but not limited to Java programs):

```
 <target name="run">
    <exec executable="name-of-executable-file">
      <arg value="${arg0}"/>
      <arg value="${arg1}"/>
    </exec>
  </target>
```

Here's the task to run a Java program from a .jar file:

```
  <target name="run-java">
    <java executable="path for jar">
      <arg value="${arg0}"/>
      <arg value="${arg1}"/>
    </java>
  </target>
```

You can invoke either from the command line like this:

```
ant -Darg0=Hello -Darg1=World run
```

Updated task

```
<target name="run" depends="jar">
        <java fork="true" classname="${main-class}">
            <classpath>
             <path location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
            </classpath>
            <arg value="${arg0}" />
        <arg value="${arg1}" />
        </java>
    </target>
```

Comment: i getting error: java doesn't support the "executable" attribute

Comment: try it with the updated task that I have written using your task. It should work in your case

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `<java>` task [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html)

> Use nested `<arg>` and `<jvmarg>` elements to specify arguments for the
>   Java class and the forked VM respectively.

and the `<arg>` [subtask](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg)